# three.js inside a Electron Desktop app

Tags: javascript, three.js, electron

I am trying to create a desktop app with contain lib three.js.

My scene contains the following :

- Mesh ( sphere geometry )
- Points ( particle )
- Directional Light
- Ambient Light

When i run the html page on browser i see the intended result which is a sphere and few points on the map but when i run the electron app i am not able to see the points only the mesh but if hide the mesh ( visible = false ) then points can be seen and if i turn back on the visibility the points disapper.

TLR - The Points Alone in scene can be seen but with combination of points and mesh points does not seems to render

Comment: Im not sure about this specific issue, but maybe try loading it in a webview: https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-view-tag.md